# what is the difference between renormalized solution and entropy solutions for nonlinear elliptic PDE?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

I want to know the difference between renormalized solution and entropy solutions for nonlinear elliptic PDE when right hand side of the elliptic operator is $L^1.$ Also how does right hand side with bounded redon measure is more general than $L^1$ right hand side.

Comment: This question is too random. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Suppose $-\Delta u=f$ and $f\in L^1(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. How do we define renormalized solution and entropy solution for this problem? Second question is that how does $-\Delta u=\mu$ where $\mu$ is a bounded Radon measure, then how does this generalizes earlier problem?